# react-native weekly agenda calendar with persian (jalali) support

Tags: react-native, calendar, persian-calendar, agenda, jalali-calendar

I need weekly agenda calendar in persian for my app but I did not find any. I want to know that is there any weekly agenda calendar exists with persian support?